# Getting "awk: cmd. line:1: Unexpected token"

Tags: ssh, awk

When I run below cmd on the Controller machine

```
Controller> echo DateTime Rd_avgMsec Wr_avgMsec; stats --diff --sho --int 60 --perf e2lxsplunkinx02-Hotdata --iosize --from 2016-10-11,00:00:00 --to 2016-10-11,00:03:00 | awk 'BEGIN{c=0} /^[0-9]|_avg/ {if (/^[0-9]/){printf "%s", $1;c++}else{ printf " %s", $NF/1000; c++ ; if(c==3){print ""; c=0}}}'
```

I get below output:

```
DateTime Rd_avgMsec Wr_avgMsec
2016-10-11,00:01:00 2.732 0.21
2016-10-11,00:02:00 1.919 0.294
2016-10-11,00:03:00 1.856 0.22
```

But when I am trying to execute the same cmd remotely on Controller machine I am getting an error `"awk: cmd. line:1: Unexpected token"` . I am trying to run the cmd remotely from launchpad01 linux machine. Can any one help me fix the error?

```
[root@launchpad01 ~]# ssh admin@Controller "echo DateTime Rd_avgMsec Wr_avgMsec; stats --diff --sho --int 60 --perf e2lxsplunkinx02-Hotdata --iosize --from 2016-10-11,00:00:00 --to 2016-10-11,00:03:00 | awk 'BEGIN{c=0} /^[0-9]|_avg/ {if (/^[0-9]/){printf "%s", $1;c++}else{ printf " %s", $NF/1000; c++ ; if(c==3){print ""; c=0}}}'"
Warning: Permanently added 'Controller' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password:
DateTime Rd_avgMsec Wr_avgMsec
awk: cmd. line:1: Unexpected token
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a quoting issue. Most simply solved in this case by running the awk pipe locally:

```
ssh admin@Controller "stats --diff --sho --int 60 --perf e2lxsplunkinx02-Hotdata --iosize --from 2016-10-11,00:00:00 --to 2016-10-11,00:03:00" |\
  awk 'BEGIN{c=0; print "DateTime","Rd_avgMsec","Wr_avgMsec";} /^[0-9]|_avg/ {if (/^[0-9]/){printf "%s", $1;c++}else{ printf " %s", $NF/1000; c++ ; if(c==3){print ""; c=0}}}'
```

Comment: @romainia You're right. I've put it into the `awk` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to run the awk pipe locally like suggested in *rudimeier*'s answer, try escaping the double quotes inside your command:

```
ssh admin@Controller "echo DateTime Rd_avgMsec Wr_avgMsec; \
stats --diff --sho --int 60 --perf e2lxsplunkinx02-Hotdata --iosize --from 2016-10-11,00:00:00 --to 2016-10-11,00:03:00 | \
awk 'BEGIN{c=0} /^[0-9]|_avg/ {if (/^[0-9]/){printf \"%s\", $1;c++}else{ printf \" %s\", $NF/1000; c++ ; if(c==3){print \"\"; c=0}}}'"
```